# Link html without underline (text-decoration: none doesn't work)

Tags: html, hyperlink, signature, underline, text-decorations

Writing an html signature, **"text-decoration: none;"** (applied to one link) works only in case i open the html file with the browser. If i try to send an email with the signature, underlining returns.

Here's my code:

```
<a href="Link to the site"style="text-decoration: none; color:#C45911">https://Link </a>
```

Comment: Email programs are notoriously not compliant with CSS the same as web browsers are.

Comment: @ivar unfortunately no

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is here. Are you trying to ask "When I [do something] to send this from my email client [insert name of email client here], the underline CSS is removed and nobody who receives the email can see it?" **or** "When I send this in an HTML formatted email people using [insert name of email client] still see the underline, how can I work around this?" (or are you trying to ask something else)?

Comment: @Quentin i use exchange. i've written my html signature (only html, no CSS), i've opened it on my browser, i've copied it and the i've created a new signature. when I go to add the signature to an new email it doesn't give any problems but when the recipient receives the email underlining returns

Answer (score 0):

I guess `text-decoration: none` property is working just fine. There are two possible problem:
1: some other stylesheet is changing the properties of `a:link` 
2: if you are using frameworks like react, angular your css is compiled first and the other css files are applied afterwards.
You can check which css file is changing your `a:link` tag's property on Chrome using `ctrl+alt+c` and click on top of your link

Comment: Yes,  text-decoration: none works but when i create the new signature and i send it, the the recipient receives the email with underlined link. i didn't use any CSS code